# Neo4j - understanding cypher querying

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm quite new to Neo4j and Cypher.
I have written the following query:

```
MATCH (tp: TPPRODUCT_VERSION {TPPRODUCTCODE: "Z1115"})
<-[:IS_TPBOMPARENT_OF]-(pv: PRODUCT_VERSION)
<-[:IS_BOMPARENT_OF*..]-(parent: PRODUCT_VERSION)
RETURN parent, pv, tp
```

Here is the result:
http://postimg.org/image/ve76qy977/

Actually I was expecting to get all Product_Versions that have a [IS_TPBOMPARENT_OF] relation to Z1115 plus their parents, no matter if they have one or not.

But instead I only got these PRODUCT_VERSIONs which have parents all which don't seem to be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you probably want to use [OPTIONAL MATCH](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-optional-match.html).

Your query forces neo4j to match a certain pattern.  If the pattern doesn't exist, then you don't get your matched data back.  In this case you want all `PRODUCT_VERSION`s, not just the ones that have parents, also the ones that don't.

So try this query instead:

```
MATCH (tp: TPPRODUCT_VERSION {TPPRODUCTCODE: "Z1115"})<-[:IS_TPBOMPARENT_OF]-(pv: PRODUCT_VERSION)
OPTIONAL MATCH (pv)<-[:IS_BOMPARENT_OF*..]-(parent: PRODUCT_VERSION)
RETURN parent, pv, tp
```

This should return `tp`, and all `pv` objects.  But then it will also try to match further from the `pv` objects to the `parent` objects, and return them if they exist.   But if they don't exist, you should still get `pv`s that don't have a `parent`.

Comment: Thats actually exactly what i was searching for!
Thanks a lot! :)